# VBA msgbox number formatting

Tags: excel, vba, messagebox

I am trying to insert a message box in excel which is part of the macro I made for certain calculation. 
Well, my macro does GoalSeek function, and at the end I want it to show the calculated value in the message box. The problem arises because when macro does calculation and shows result which is percentage number from excel sheet, it is formatted like `0.8383854828321838`, and I want it to be formatted as percentage, like it is in excel worksheet, like `83,84%`. Is it possible to format cell value in VBA `MsgBox`?!?! Can you help me about this?!

I pasted here the code from vba for you to see how it looks at the moment.

```
Sub Anuitet()
    range("O2").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=range("O5")
    range("O3").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=range("F2")

    MsgBox "Efektivna kamatna stopa za konfigurisani aranžman je " & range("f2").Value & ".", vbOKOnly, "Obracun efektivne kamatne stope"

End Sub
```

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302795/how-do-i-apply-a-custom-format-such-as-text-0-0-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
MsgBox "Efektivna kamatna stopa za konfigurisani aranžman je " & Format(Range("f2").Value, "0.00%")
```

(with an adjustment if necessary for your local number format)